# What is the appropriate substitution for this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to solve this equation:
$x^\frac{1}{3}+x^\frac{1}{7}=2(x^5)^\frac{1}{21}.$

I can't find the substitution which reduces it to a system or equation without roots.

Comment: Setting $x = y^{3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7} = y^{105}$ would turn it into a polynomial equation with a large degree. EDIT: Is the right side actually supposed to be $2x^{5/21}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you for noticing.

Comment: Hint: First we can simplify the left side, x^$1/3$+x^$1/7$=(x^$4/21$+1)x^($1/7$)

Comment: I think $x = y^{21}$ would be fine, not necessarily $x = y^{105}$.

Comment: Yes, $x = y^{21}$ is just fine. I mistakenly thought the $5$ was in the denominator instead of the numerator of the exponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\text{The equation can be rewritten as follows:}$$

$$x^{\frac{7}{21}} + x^{\frac{3}{21}} = 2(x^{\frac{5}{21}})$$

$$$$

$$\text{Now, let } y = x^{\frac{1}{21}}:$$

$$y^7 + y^3 = 2y^5 \implies y^7 - 2y^5 + y^3 = 0$$

$$$$

$$\text{If } y = 0, \text{ then } x = 0, \text{ else we have: }$$

$$y^4 - 2y^2 + 1 = 0 \implies (y^2 - 1)^2 = 0 \implies y^2 = 1$$

$$$$

$$\text{Hence, } y \in \{-1, 0, 1\}.$$

$$\text{And thus, } x \in \{-1, 0, 1\} \text{ since } x = y^{21}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you did mean by "appropriate" substitution. But you may solve this equation as following:

$y^{21}=x$

Then you get $ y ^7 + y^3 = 2y^5 $. Therefore $ y^3(y^4-2y^2+1) = 0 $.

And you have that $y^3 = 0 $ or $ (y^4-2y^2+1) = 0 $. The second equation is biquadratic.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiquadraticEquation.html